# Build conditional statement from variables

Tags: r, matrix, filter

Given a matrix :

```
x<-letters[1:24]
dim(x)<-c(8,3)
pos<-c(4,8)
filt<-c("d","x")
```

I want to keep from `x` the columns where a row in `pos` does not equal the corresponding letter in `filt`. Manually this would look like this:

```
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "i"  "q" 
[2,] "b"  "j"  "r" 
[3,] "c"  "k"  "s" 
[4,] "d"  "l"  "t" 
[5,] "e"  "m"  "u" 
[6,] "f"  "n"  "v" 
[7,] "g"  "o"  "w" 
[8,] "h"  "p"  "x" 
> x[, apply(x, 2, function(x)(x[4] != "d" & x[8] != "x")), drop=FALSE]
     [,1]
[1,] "i" 
[2,] "j" 
[3,] "k" 
[4,] "l" 
[5,] "m" 
[6,] "n" 
[7,] "o" 
[8,] "p"
```

How do I do that for any length of `pos` and `filt`?

Comment: `function (x) all(x[pos] != filt)`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph duh thank you! I think my brain was in python mode when I asked this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset `x` with `pos` `x[pos,]` and compare it with `filt` and select cases where `colSums` equals `0`.

```
x[,colSums(x[pos,,drop=FALSE] == filt) == 0, drop=FALSE]
#     [,1]
#[1,] "i" 
#[2,] "j" 
#[3,] "k" 
#[4,] "l" 
#[5,] "m" 
#[6,] "n" 
#[7,] "o" 
#[8,] "p"
```

Comment: you just addressed my next question which would be to make it work with arrays of length 1 :)